# I want to remove image transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, workspace

I have a cloth image and it is in the transparent, background, and the object both... I want to change its color but whenever I apply any color the color is also be lite like the background. How to change the color and remove the overall opacity of that image.

Like this:

[image: this is the image that I am talking about]

Comment: put a solid layer behind and resave?

Comment: Can you share an image of how it looks when you apply colour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97458/is-there-an-inverse-eraser-tool-on-photoshop

Answer (score 3):

To fix the opacity of the image, duplicate the image layer about 5 times or more and group all those layers plus the original layer.  The result will be a fully opaque image.

The colouring is another issue.  You could select the background with the Magic Wand Tool (W), invert the selection, fill a new layer with the required colour, and change the layer blending mode to `Linear Burn`.

Example

[image: Example of coloured shirt]

Comment: Why 5 times wouldt it be better just to pull a levels on the alpha channel?

Comment: I suppose you could, either way gets the job done.  You could also just do a Merge Visible on all the layers, rather than group.

Comment: Just in case the OP wants to attempt the levels adjustment method - it's simply a case of clicking `Layers` >`Layer Mask From Transparency`, then in the Channels Panel, select the layer mask. And click `Image` > `Adjustments` > `Levels` and pull the right most slider into the middle. Example here: http://imgur.com/oaI3ozW